# How to pass jwt token in request header of react-native-webview?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-webview

How to pass jwt token in request header of react-native-webview to display protected webpages content.

The below code is not working :

```
 <WebView
 
    source={{
      uri: 'website url',
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Bearer'+'eyJ0eX...........',
      },
    }}

  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Use below code

```js
<>
      <ActivityIndicator visible={isLoading} />
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri: 'https://.....', headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }}
        onLoadStart={() => setIsLoading(false)}
      />
    </>
```

and then set the cookie from backend

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a space after Bearer: Try like:

```
<WebView
        source={{
          uri: 'website url',
          headers: {
            Authorization:
              'Bearer'+" "+'eyJ0eX...........',
          },
        }}
    
      />
```

Comment: Tried your solution, still getting redirected to the login page. 

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: No errors .Just the login screen got rendered instead of the desired screen